# json query response value shows undefined

Tags: javascript, json, odata, sapui5

I am consuming `ODATA service` to get the resulting `dataset` from a table. I get the data in `JSON format` like as shown below.

```
$.getJSON("../TEST_ODATA3.xsodata/COMPAREDATA?$format=json&$select=WERT&$filter=LIFNR eq '"+supplier+"' and ARTIKEL eq '"+artikel+"' and STOREID eq '"+storeId+"' and BUSINESS_DATE eq datetime'"+date_time+"'",
                                    function(response){
                                for (i = 0; i < response.d.results.length; i++) {
                                    console.log(response.WERT);}});
```

Everything works fine. But when I try to access the column name `WERT` from the response, I get the value as `undefined` in the browser console. But when I copy the same link including `host and port` on the browser I see the column name and the value in the response.
Can anyone tell me what I am missing in the above code. I also tried `console.log(response.d.results.WERT);`

**UPDATE** : The response looks like this:

```
{
d: {
results: [
{
__metadata: {
uri: "host:port/TEST_ODATA3.xsodata/COMPAREDATA('1')",
type: "TEST_ODATA3.COMPAREDATAType"
},
WERT: "35.26"
}
]
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the response here?

Comment: @anurupr I have made an update to my question for your reference.

Comment: try `response.d.results[0].WERT`

Comment: but the response isn't valid JSON. this is the output when you run the url separately?

Comment: @anurupr yes. This a valid json format response I get when I run the above query. Your previous suggestion works. Can you please post this as an answer below since you were first to suggest the right answer.

Comment: why arent you using the ODataModel for retrieving OData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is an array according to your json . You can access it like this

```
  response.d.results[0].WERT
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean indentation would have show you the problem.
Your object WERT is in d.results array, you must access it by `response.d.results[0].WERT`

Comment: Thank you cybril. Your suggestion was right too. Cheers!

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ can cleanup json and javascript code if needed. I often use it when receiving unformatted json code :)

Answer (score 1):

For loops I prefer to use jQuery each:

```
$.getJSON("../TEST_ODATA3.xsodata/COMPAREDATA?$format=json&$select=WERT"+
    "&$filter=LIFNR eq '"+supplier+
    "' and ARTIKEL eq '"+artikel+
    "' and STOREID eq '"+storeId+
    "' and BUSINESS_DATE eq datetime'"+date_time+"'",
    function(response){
        $.sap.each(response.d.results, function(i, oItem){
            console.log(oItem.WERT);
        });
    });
```